# What does a warning on a Java getter call from Kotlin mean?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

I'm writing the code with Kotlin, the code A can work well, but the hint of Android Studio 3.0 tell me that  `getApplicationContext()` is not good.

How can  translate the java code `getApplicationContext()` into Kotlin? Thanks!

```
class UIApp : Application() {

    companion object {
        var instance: UIApp by NotNullSingleValueVar()
    }

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        instance = this

        MobileAds.initialize( getApplicationContext(), getApplicationContext().getString(R.string.ad_app_id) );
    }

}
```

Comment: What does the hint say exactly?

Comment: And Android studio should provide assistance to apply it's suggestion. Alt/Option - Enter will popup a dialog with suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The hint tells you that you should replace the Java getter call `getApplicationContext()` with property access: `applicationContext`.

Java getters and pairs of a getter and a setter are represented as `val` and `var` [properties](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html) in Kotlin. The idiomatic way to access a Java getter is to use the property. See the language reference: [Calling Java from Kotlin. Getters and Setters](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#getters-and-setters).